# How do I read a file line by line while modifying lines as needed?

Tags: perl

In Perl, I'm trying to read a file line by line and process each line, modifying it as required.
So far, the only way I'm reading to be able to do this is read the file into an array, modify each element of the array as needed, then when it's finished, output it back to the file.

Is there a better way to do this, perhaps some way I can replace single lines as I go along?

Right now, my processing code looks like this:

```
while (my $line = <FILE>)
{
    # process line here
    # ...........

    print FILE $line;
}
```

My code seems to be very close, except that it's replacing one line after the line I'm currently in, so it seems that if I could back the file pointer up by one line, it would write to the correct place in the file.

Am I on the right track? What would I need to do from here to back up the file pointer so it writes to the same line I'm reading from?

---

*Edit:*

Out of the answers I received, both using `local $^I` and [`Tie::File`](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aFile) worked nicely.
I ended up going with `Tie::File` so I wouldn't have to print out every line of the file. This way if something happens midway through the script, my file won't be messed up.

My new code looks like this:

```
use Tie::File;

chomp(my $filename = $ARGV[0]);
tie my @array, 'Tie::File', $filename or die $!;

foreach my $line(@array)
{
    # ...... line processing happens here .......
    # ...... $line is automatically written to file if $line is changed .......
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to read from a file and write to it at the same time like you do.

You could use [`Tie::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html). It ties the lines of a file to an array. You can modify the array as you need which in turn modifies the file transparently in the background.

Answer (score 7):

> What would I need to do from here to back up the file pointer so it writes to the same line I'm reading from?

This doesn't help, unless every line you intend to write is the same length as the line you're replacing (in which case the tools you're looking for are [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) and [tell](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html)). For ordinary editing though, the standard file model just doesn't cut it for replacing bits in-place.

Fortunately, Perl comes with a feature that makes what you need easy, called "in-place editing mode", in which the source file is either renamed or unlinked, and the output directed to a new file with the same name. Most often it's used by enabling the `-i` [command-line switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) together with the `-p` or `-n` switches for line-wise editing, but you can also enable it within a program using the `$^I` [special variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Example code:

```
{   # Create a scope to localize variables in.
    # If you want to back up the originals, set $^I to ".bak" instead.
    local $^I = "";
    # Set @ARGV to the file you want to process, or a list of files.
    local @ARGV = ("file.txt");

    while (my $line = <>) {
        # Process $line here.
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May not be relevant to the problem, but quick changes to a file in-place can be done on the command line, e.g.

```
# convert MS line endings to UNIX:
perl -p -i -e 's{\r\n}{\n}' my_file.txt
```

The line is $_ in the code (the argument to -e) and the line is printed out, so it's an in-place version of something like this:

```
perl -e '$line = $_; $line =~ s{\r\n}{\n}; print $line' < windows.txt > unix.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do it as supposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713537/displaying-a-message-to-users-pre-commit-in-tortoise-svn/4718459#4718459) (see `sub precommit_hook`):

First, read in the whole file into an array:

```
open my $handle,'<:utf8',$name 
    or croak "Error reading file contents of $name\n";
my @content = <$handle>;
close $handle or croak "unable to close";
```

Then, process each line of the array and write it out to the file:

```
# now, write it, ignoring the comment lines
open my $handle, '>:utf8', $name
or croak "Opening $name for writing failed\n";
flock $handle, LOCK_EX;

foreach my $line(@content){
  # TODO: modify the line here
  print {$handle} $line . "\n";
}

close $handle or croak "unable to close";
```

The downside of this is that the whole file gets re-written and if you exit too soon (e.g. during debugging), the file is messed up.

Comment: You should never use `flock $fh, LOCK_UN` to unlock a file if all you're about to do is close it anyway. `close` will unlock the file when it closes it, but first it will flush any data that hasn't been written written yet, preventing a race.

Comment: @hobbs: that's why I love SO: you answer something and then someone more competent comes along and tells you that the way you're doing it is not right. Thanks for teaching me!