# How to delete lines from file after reading it?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a code like this -

```
     > for line in `cat file.txt`;do 
     /*if line-1 dosomething-1 */
     /*if line-2 dosomething-2 */
     /* if line-3 dosomething-3 */
     //Parsing 3 lines I would like to remove them from file - how to do that?
     //Parse - line4 
     //Parse - line5 
     //Parse - line6
     //now delete above 3 lines again & repeat the process till eof.\
     done
```

I just need to delete the lines after its processed

Comment: If you could use Perl, answers to this question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732937/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-while-modifying-lines-as-needed/4733306#4733306

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change a file as you're reading it, so you'll need to output the entries you want to keep to a new file (or stdout), and skip the entries you don't.   Then the resulting file can be processed further with only the kept lines.